# Merge [fop] with [apache-fop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

My question is about the infrequently used tags [fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop) and [apache-fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fop).

Both tags refer to the Apache implementation of a Formatting Objects Processor.  I believe that they should be merged under [apache-fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fop) with wiki from [fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop).

I found an old synonym request between the two that lists [fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop) as a master (which is used somewhat more: 509 vs 178). Since both tags currently have the same purpose and [apache-fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fop) has a more specific name, I believe that it should remain and [fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop) might be re-purposed for *vendor-neutral* implementations of the specs.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be dandy to merge [fop] with [apache-fop]?" Sorry, might be a bit too esoteric a word for word play :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan We're all Dapper Dan men (women, small fuzzy green creatures from Alpha Centauri, etc) here.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan not for people who get the joke! there's always going to be people who don't. can't worry about them.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  - I never knew that "fop" was anything but the abbreviation.

Answer (score 12):

I agree that the primary tag should be [apache-fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fop).

I disagree that [fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop) should be re-purposed for vendor-neutral implementations of the [Formatting Objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#fo-section) portion of the [W3C Extensible Stylesheet Language (XSL) Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/).  History and common usage simply don't support such an association.  ***XSL-FO Processor*** is commonly used to refer in a vendor-neutral manner to implementations of the XSL-FO spec.  Apache FOP is well-known as ***FOP***, therefore [fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop) should be a synonym of [apache-fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fop).

Comment: OK. Works too.  Now who can make it happen?

Comment: Yes, we've got [tag:xsl-fo] for the vendor neutral case. I hope there is no problem distinguishing it from [Feature-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature-oriented_programming), because of course there is a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[fop]+feature+oriented).